# Location of Java RSocket Fire And Forget send Payload to other connect client

Tags: spring, chat, rsocket, fire-and-forget, webflux

I make some project use RSocket, and i [refer](https://medium.com/swlh/building-a-chat-application-with-angular-and-spring-rsocket-3cd8013f2f55) that post, I want know where implement code send Message to other client logic.

```
    @MessageMapping("send")
    public Mono<Void> sendMessage(String p) {
        return this.messages.save(new Message(p, Instant.now())).log().then();
    }

    @MessageMapping("messages")
    public Flux<Message> messageStream() {
        return this.messages.getMessageBy().log();
    }
```

My project [link](https://github.com/leeseojune53/TIL/tree/master/BackEnd_Learn/Java/rsocket_server)
I search Docs, Post... but no Information :((

Comment: Are you trying to send messages to the client from the server? or asking about how to write the client code in JS etc?